# Flutter PUB CACHE CLEAN via Jenkins Pipeline Script On MacOS Agent Getting Stuck

Tags: flutter, jenkins, continuous-integration

I have a Jenkins LTS Controller Version 2.426.3 Running on Java 11. I have connected a MacOS agent via SSH to the Jenkins controller.

When I run "flutter pub cache clean -f" via freestyle project through a "Execute Shell" step, the command runs successfully.
But when I run the same command via a Pipeline Script, the command gets stuck/it keeps running almost indefinitely.

PS: The command runs properly on Windows agent both in Freestyle project and Jenkins Scripted Pipeline
[image: Freestyle Project Successful Execution]

Pipeline Script

```
pipeline {
    agent {label 'mac1'}

    stages {
        stage('Hello') {
            steps {
                sh 'flutter pub cache clean -f -v'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Scripted Pipeline Simply keeps Running]